# The private key for code signing is missing

Tags: objective-c

The error xCode 5.1.1 is giving me ...

"The private key for code signing is missing".

The problem is the certificate is sitting on my desktop and its already in my keychain. I double clicked it for installation.

It gives me an option to import a profile or "revoke and request." I don't want to revoke a good profile and when I click to import, all the files are greyed out.

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

1) In xCode go to xCode-preferances-accounts-view details.

2) look at the status of each certificate

if (certificate status != @"Vaild") 
{

1) go to the developer portal and select certificate tab.

2)  delete certificates != @"Valid" status in the certificates.

2a) delete the certificates from keychain if they are there.

3) follow the steps to regenerate and install the certificates by clicking the + button in the certificates section.

4) regenerate the dev and distribution provisioning profiles as needed.

}